# turning data into a list

Tags: list, sorting, python-3.x, transform

I have combined two .txt files using a program i wrote.  Now once i combined these two .txt files i was left with an unsorted combination of data.

my data looks like this

```
Bud Abbott 51 92.3
Mary Boyd 52 91.4
Hillary Clinton 50 82.1
Don Adams 51 90.4
Jill Carney 53 76.3
Randy Newman 50 41.2
```

however i want it to look like this

```
 ['Bud', 'Abbott', 51, 92.3]
 ['Don', 'Adams', 51, 90.4]
 ['Mary', 'Boyd', 52, 91.4]
 ['Jill', 'Carney', 53, 76.3]
 ['Hillary', 'Clinton', 50, 82.1]
 ['Randy', 'Newman', 50, 41.2]
```

how do i transform what i have into what i want

by the way the code i have to get my first set of data looks like this

```
def ReadAndMerge():

     library1=input("Enter 1st filename to read and merge:")
     with open(library1, 'r') as library1names:
          library1contents = library1names.read()
     library2=input("Enter 2nd filename to read and merge:")
     with open(library2, 'r') as library2names:
          library2contents = library2names.read()

     print(library1contents)
     print(library2contents)
     combined_contents = library1contents + library2contents  # concatenate text



     file = combined_contents
     lines = []

     for l in file:
          line = l.strip().split(" ")
          lines.append(line)


     lines.sort(key=lambda lines: lines[1])

     for line in lines:
          print(line)

print(combined_contents)
return(combined_contents)
```

ReadAndMerge()

and library 1 and library 2 look like this respectively

```
Bud Abbott 51 92.3
Mary Boyd 52 91.4
Hillary Clinton 50 82.1



Don Adams 51 90.4
Jill Carney 53 76.3
Randy Newman 50 41.2
```

How do i get it to be sorted and in a list

I updated my program with your new lines, but when i run it i keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Shane/Documents/Amer CISC/readandmerge.py", line 30, in <module>
ReadAndMerge()
 File "C:/Users/Shane/Documents/Amer CISC/readandmerge.py", line 23, in ReadAndMerge
lines.sort(key=lambda lines: lines[1])
 File "C:/Users/Shane/Documents/Amer CISC/readandmerge.py", line 23, in <lambda>
lines.sort(key=lambda lines: lines[1])
 IndexError: list index out of range
 >>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def getListOfLinesInFile(file): 
    file = open(file, "r")
    lines = []    
    for l in file:
        line = l.strip().split(" ")
        lines.append(line)
    file.close()
    return lines
```

To use it in your program, just your `ReadAndMerge` -function with:

```
def ReadAndMerge():
    library1 = input("Enter 1st filename to read and merge: ")
    library1_list = getListOfLinesInFile(library1)

    library2 = input("Enter 2nd filename to read and merge: ")
    library2_list = getListOfLinesInFile(library1)

    library_merged = library1_list + library2_list
    library_merged.sort(key=lambda library_merged: library_merged[1])

    print(*library_merged)
    return library_merged
```

Comment: but since i want to sort them by last name not first name do i just call there location in the list

Comment: what your program did was turn every single letter, number and space into its own list, take bud abbott 51, 92.3 and turned it into['B'], ['u'], ['d'], [''], ['A'], ['b'], ['b'], ['o'], ['t'], ['t'], [''], ['5'], ['1'], [''], ['9'], ['2'], ['.'], ['3']  i need it to be ['Bud', 'Abbott', 51, 92.3]

Comment: I did a minor edit to the code, but it should've worked earlier too, and it works fine for me. It's designed to open the file which has all the merged data inside it, make sure your text file is exactly similar to the text you have in your main post's first code box.

Comment: ok i think i see where my problem is.  You have wrote a program that works off of a file location where as my data, is just in a variable name location.  as you can see from my code above all of those names are inside the variable name combined_contents.  Do you know if you can edit your program to work off a variable name or do you know how i could make combined_contents into a file location

Comment: I did edit it a little, this will get rid of the original text, but you should be able to edit it to your liking with just a little bit of research and help of google. I'm not quite sure which data do you need to save, it currenlty returns only a list with both files in it.

Comment: Glad to help, hopefully you got what you needed. :)