# Is it possible to use code to transform a list in format 'list': "translation"?

Tags: javascript, python, html, database, list

I would like to be able to change a list of words in my coding, e.g.

```
var words= { 
AFK Away from the keyboard 4U For you B4N By for now BBL Be back later BDAY Birthday CBA Can't be asked  }
```

changed to this format:

```
var words= {
'AFK': "Away from the keyboard", '4U': "For you", 'B4N': "By for now", 'BBL': "Be back      later", 'BDAY': "Birthday", 'CBA': "Can't be asked", 
  }
```

without having to change each word into the format manually using HTML/JavaScript. However I understand that this might not be possible, but I thought I'd see if anyone had an I idea on how to do it anyway. From what I read it looks as if I'll have to use Python and a Database, but I don't know anything about python what so ever really so I was hoping (probably vainly) that there is some HTML/JavaScript code that I haven't seen that solves this!

I found a similar question here, but it wasn't really what I wanted as it uses python: [[turning data into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458430/turning-data-into-a-list])

The thing I want to do is change all words in this format: e.g 
   AFK Away from the Keyboard

to a format with 
'AFK': "Away from the keyboard",

the aim of this code is to translate text abbreviations to real English words which it is already doing, but in order to get a decent amount of words to translate I need to get words in the above format which would take forever if I formated each one individually. here is the rest of the code if that helps:

```
function replacer() {
var text= document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
for (var modifiers in translationwords){ 
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + modifiers + '\\b', 'gi'), translationwords[modifiers]); }
document.getElementById("textbox2").value=text;
document.getElementById("add").onclick= function storage() {  
if(!document.cookie) document.cookie = "";   
document.cookie = document.cookie +"<li>"+document.getElementById("textbox1").value+ ":"+"</li>";
document.cookie = document.cookie +"<li>" + document.getElementById("textbox2").value+ "</li>";
document.getElementById("array").innerHTML= document.cookie;
}

}   




function textdelete(x) {
if (x.value=="ENTER TRANSLATION HERE"){
x.value="";
};
}
```

Thank You

Comment: How is your code ending up in that form in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you'd need Python and a database. I can't even imagine what a database would be doing here, and pretty much anything you can do with Python you can do with Javascript.

Comment: That is not valid Javascript. What created that `words` non-object?

Comment: start by explaining the source of the current data.

Comment: I was under the impression that [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458430/turning-data-into-a-list] involved Python, I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If your words were in a string to begin with, then it would be arguably possible to translate it into an object the way you want it, but it might not be the most accurate translation.

Since it looks like all the abbreviations are all upper case and without spaces, we can look through the string, and set the all caps/numbers 'words' as properties, with the following string of text as the value.  In javascript, something like this would work.

```
//set words as string
var string = "AFK Away from the keyboard 4U For you B4N By for now BBL Be back later BDAY Birthday CBA Can't be asked";

// create empty dictionary for storage
var dictionary = {};   

// use regex to find all abbreviations and store them in an array
var abbreviations = string.match(/[A-Z0-9]+(?![a-z])\w/g);   
// returns ["AFK", "4U", "B4N", "BBL", "BDAY", "CBA"] 

// use regex to replace all abbreviations with commas... 
englishWords = string.replace(/[A-Z0-9]+(?![a-z])\w/g, ','); 
  // Edit (see below):
englishWords = englishWords.replace(/\W,\W/g,',');
  // End edit 
// then split string into array based on commas
englishWords = englishWords.split(',').slice(1);  

// finally loop over all abbreviations and add them to the dictionary with their meaning.
for(var i = 0; i < abbreviations.length; i++){
    dictionary[abbreviations[i]] = englishWords[i];
}
```

Edit:  the above solution still might have white space at the beginning or end of each english string.  You can add this line of code just before splitting the string to remove the white space.

```
englishWords = englishWords.replace(/\W,\W/g,',');
```

Comment: how would I call the result of the code? e.g. so the `"ABBREVIATION": "translation",` is physically on a page?

Comment: The result of the code is an object that contains all the translations.  The object is named 'dictionary', so you could access it as a regular javascript object, with something like dictionary.AFK or dictionary['AFK']. (or some abbreviation other than AFK)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the data as a list in python, or as a string, or that you can get it into that format:

```
>>> lst = 'AFK Away from the keyboard 4U For you B4N By for now BBL Be back later BDAY Birthday CBA Can\'t be asked'.split()
>>> lst
['AFK', 'Away', 'from', 'the', 'keyboard', '4U', 'For', 'you', 'B4N', 'By', 'for', 'now', 'BBL', 'Be', 'back', 'later', 'BDAY', 'Birthday', 'CBA', "Can't", 'be', 'asked']
```

Further assuming that the keywords are always in all-uppercase and that the values are never in all uppercase, and that there are no duplicate keys, you can create the following dictionary:

```
>>> keys = [x for x in lst if x.upper() == x]
>>> {keys[i]:' '.join(lst[lst.index(keys[i]):lst.index(keys[i+1])]) for i in range(len(keys)-1)}
{'BDAY': 'BDAY Birthday', 'BBL': 'BBL Be back later', '4U': '4U For you', 'B4N': 'B4N By for now', 'AFK': 'AFK Away from the keyboard'}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid python as i don't know anything about it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that this is your list of words:

```
["AFK","Away","from","the","keyboard","4U","For","you","B4N","By","for","now","BBL","Be","back","later","BDAY","Birthday","CBA","Can't","be","asked"]
```

Now, we can change that into an object simply by using regular JavaScript without any database or back-end langauge like Python.

```
var list = ["AFK","Away","from","the","keyboard","4U","For","you","B4N","By","for","now","BBL","Be","back","later","BDAY","Birthday","CBA","Can't","be","asked"] /*What we have*/;
var code = {} /*What we want*/;
var currKey = null /*Our current key*/, hasBeenSet = false /*Whether or not the property at our current key has been set*/;
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    //If the current word is an abbreviation...
    if (words[i] === words[i].toUpperCase()) {
        currKey = words[i]; //We set currKey to it
        hasBeenSet = false; //We make hasBeenSet false
    }
    //Otherwise, if the property at current key has been set, we add on to it.
    else if (hasBeenSet) code[currKey] += " "+words[i];
    //Otherwise, the property at current key hasn't been set...
    else {
        code[currKey] = words[i]; //We set the property to the current word
        hasBeenSet = true; //We make hasBeenSet true
    }
}
code //{ AFK: "Away from the keyboard", 4U: "For you", B4N: "By for now", BBL: "Be back later", BDAY:"Birthday", CBA:"Can't be asked" }
```